# Detect if threading is allowed/possible in Python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to detect if I'm allowed to spawn threads in a Python script, and if those threads actually get started (some environments, e.g. uwsgi, may restrict threading).

The only idea I had so far was to actually start a thread which sets a flag, and then check that flag from the main thread:

```
import time
import threading


class MyObj(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.threading_available = False
        thread = threading.Thread(target=self._set_threading_available)
        thread.start()
        time.sleep(0.005)
        # do work depending on wether self.threading_available is True or False

    def _set_threading_available(self):
        self.threading_available = True
```

Are there better approaches that don't incur this overhead (having to sleep for a short span of time in the main thread, and the overhead of creating a thread)?

Comment: On a platform where threads don't work, what happens when you "create" one?  Do you get `None` back from `Thread()`?  What if you try to `join()` on such a platform?  Is there a way to simulate the environment you're talking about?  Otherwise I don't know how to test these things!

Comment: @JohnZwinck here's a minimal example using flask/uwsgi. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like `enable-threads = false` actually disables threads, at least in my tests... https://gist.github.com/piquadrat/84a129b450d3e2ffc9a9

Comment: So is there *any* way that an of us can reproduce an environment where threads can't spawn?  I could even hack something together myself if I knew some of the answers to my questions in the previous comment.

Comment: the only way I found so far is to build python with `./configure --without-threads`, in which case `import threading` simply fails with an `ImportError`. I'm still trying to find out why in the case of `uwsgi`, disabling threads doesn't work.

Comment: Right, well, if `import threading` fails that's super easy to check!